# How to change the colour errors/warnings/suggestions in the Resharper bar

Tags: resharper

I am red/green colour blind and I find that the default palette used by the "resharper bar" makes suggestions and errors hard to differentiate - especially if the file has a lot of suggestions.

{By "resharper bar" I mean the bar on the right hand side of the text editor window (see http://imagebin.org/107149)}

Is there any way of changing these colours?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 (and 2010 some time soon hopefully!)

Comment: It's officially called the "Marker Bar". http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Continuous_Code_Quality_Analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible to customise these colours. I'd recommend logging a support call with JetBrains directly.

Comment: You are correct - I just got this from support:  "I'm afraid those colors cannot be changed at the moment. We've received similar requests and we will discuss if this can be addressed in one of the future releases".  Jetbrains are usually pretty good at responding to user feature requests - so hopefully this will be added soon.